# Apple Watch contact names missing after watchOS 3 update

Tags: messages, contacts, apple-watch

After updating my Apple Watch to watchOS 3 some of my contact names are missing in Messages and Phone etc. Some are showing name, others just show the phone number. The iPhone does show the contact names where the watch doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This answer's a bit late, but I finally figured out the issue.

**Your Apple Watch's contact list is most likely out of sync with your iPhone.**

[image: Apple watch - Phone app]

Try checking your Apple Watch's contact list though the phone app. If it looks like some contacts are missing, it's likely that the contact list isn't synced properly.

The easiest way to manually re-sync your contact list is to create a dummy contact "AAAAA" on your iPhone. Once it's been resynced, all your contacts should start displaying properly again.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It was keeping me from sending texts through Siri on the WATCH and driving me crazy. It may help to have the Phone app open on WATCH while following those steps. I also had to do it a second time after opening the Messages app on the WATCH.

Comment: @Phong Glad to help. Bizarrely, the issue only affected my most commonly used contacts, so I was lucky to find a solution.

Comment: @SteveVascellaro Did you delete the **Contacts** app from your iPhone, by any chance?

Comment: @Phong No, I've never deleted the contacts app. TIL it is possible to delete the contacts app on an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Just found an answer!
Must have been a glitch or something. Just unpaired my watch and repaired it using the backup and everything is like normal.